# How-To Convert IQueryable Expression Tree to Lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

How can i convert a `IQueryable Expression` Tree to a `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` Expression.

```
IQueryable<Book> Books;

var query = Books.Where(p => p.Author.AuthorId == 5);

Expression<Func<Book, bool>> expression = ?????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the [IQueryable.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.expression.aspx) Property to access the *IQueryable*'s Expression tree.

Comment: can u elaborate your answer please ? maybe with an exemple

Comment: Hello Yoann, what would you like to do with the Expression tree?  Or, what is the big picture?

Comment: actually i want to convert a IQueryable Chain such as Books.WithAuthorName("Mike").WithTitle("Something") to a single Expression

Answer (score 3):

```
Expression<Func<Book, bool>> expression = p => p.Author.AuthorId == 5;
```